# Precompile handlebars partials only

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there a way to precompile handlebars partials only? I want to leave the variables in tact, but simply assemble the page beforehand.

Here is *should* the use-case:

1. Partials get included in a `.hbs` template
2. Template can undergo minification/alteration of the HTML with `{{foo}}` variables in tact.
3. New `.hbs` template can be compiled.

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to combine handlebars partials together as a compile step. In other words, only process `{{>header}}`, don’t process `{{name}}`

Comment: Please fix the question text carefully. There are several grammar problems that make figuring out what you mean problematic. An example would help too.

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh example provided

Answer (score 2):

```js
Handlebars.registerPartial('header', 'im the header, hi \\{{name}}');
Handlebars.registerPartial('footer', 'im the footer, hi \\{{name}}');

document.write(Handlebars.compile('{{>header}}im the body, hi \\{{name}}{{>footer}}')({}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
```